# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Here I am taking a number longer than nine digits, breaking up the number into groups of nine digits and storing it in an array. 
When I run this code to store the value inside arrayOfNumbers, I am thrown an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
 public BigNum(String s) {
    if (badNum(s)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();     //Exception to check for invalid input
    }

    int arraySize = 1;
    num = s;
    int [] arrayOfNumbers = new int[arraySize];
    int numSize = s.length();

    if (numSize <= 9)
    {
        arraySize = 1;
        arrayOfNumbers[0] = Integer.parseInt(s);         //THIS CLAUSE IS WORKING
    }
    else if((numSize % 9) >= 1) {
        arraySize = ((numSize % 9) + 1);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 9;
        int[] evenString = new int[arraySize];                  
        for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++){


            String w = s.substring(x,y);

            arrayOfNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(w); //THIS LINE IS FAILING *********

            if(i == arraySize - 2){
                x = x + 9;
                y = y + (numSize % 9);
            }
            else{
                y = y + 9;
                x = x + 9;
            }


        }

        System.out.println(arraySize);
    }
    else if((numSize % 9 == 0)) {
        arraySize = (numSize/9);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 9;

        for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++){

            String w = s.substring(x,y);
            int[] evenString = new int[arraySize];      //THIS CLAUSE IS WORKING

            y = y*2;
            x = x+9;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please put initialization of **arrayOfNumbers**

Comment: i think `arraySize` should be `numSize / 9`, not `numSize % 9`?

Comment: Rather than starting your sample with an `else` clause, please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - including which line is failing.

Comment: Here, I will edit my post and comment in the stuck line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning to arrayOfNumbers which you initialize to only have one element. Did you mean to assign to evenString instead? evenString is initialized with the correct array size for this loop.

You could also just declare arrayOfNumbers to be the same size as the evenString array. For example:

```
int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[arraySize];                  
for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++){


    String w = s.substring(x,y);

    arrayOfNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(w); //THIS LINE IS FAILING *********

    if(i == arraySize - 2){
        x = x + 9;
        y = y + (numSize % 9);
    }
    else{
        y = y + 9;
        x = x + 9;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a clean way to do that?